# Display encapsulated widget in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an object that encapsulates a widget.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
```

I want this object to display itself as this widget in the notebook.

```
>>> my_widget
<fancy widget>

>>> Foo(my_widget)
<fancy widget>
```

Is there a method that I should implement on my `Foo` class to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ipywidgets piggy backs onto IPython's rich display system.  `_ipython_display_` is a hook in the system that allows you to intercept display calls.  Try the following:

```
    class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self, widget):
            self.widget = widget

        def _ipython_display_(self, **kwargs):
            self.widget._ipython_display_(**kwargs)
```

Cheers,
Jon

Edit: [Here's](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb) the relevant example file included with ipython.  Scroll down to "More complex display"...